# MongoDB (3.2) doesn't start on Lubuntu 16.04 LTS as a service

Tags: lubuntu, 16.04, mongodb

For whatever reason, whenever I try to start MongoDB as a service (`sudo service mongod start`) I get the following error:

```
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
```

I followed the installation guide on the MongoDB site.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The instructions/packages on the MongoDB site are currently available for LTS Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 only. The packages are set up to use upstart instead of systemd. You need to create a systemctl file to be ready for systemd. Create it by

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service
```

It will look like

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now you can start the service and check its state by

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

and finally enable it permanently by

```
sudo systemctl enable mongodb
```

(Source: [How to Install MongoDB on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04))

Comment: Sometimes it fails to start by an NETWORK error. In such case try deleting the sock file in /tmp

Comment: The official way to do it is to use mongod for the service name

Comment: Followed these instructions and tried to run sudo systemctl start mongodb, but received the following error message: "Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service is masked." Running "sudo systemctl unmask mongodb" fixed the error

Comment: you just saved my day

Comment: Thanks a log JeffRSon, it saved my day, I was struggling to get this working.

Answer (score 5):

Just run `sudo mongod` to start the daemon and then `sudo mongo` to access the shell

Comment: Do you always run databases on your servers this way?

Comment: sadly this worked for me... So I needed to change permissions to mongo user

Comment: this worked for me, but I also needed to cd /, then sudo mkdir data then sudo mkdir /data/db.

Answer (score 1):

Running following command worked for me. Please run mongo with config file.
Just Run `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`.

Comment: this option is removed in mongo 3.6.6